# Why is cleverness considered harmful in programming by some people?

Tags: abstraction

I've noticed a lot of questions lately relating to different abstraction techniques, and answers saying basically that the techniques in question are "too clever." I would think that part of our jobs as programmers is to determine the best solutions to the problems we are given to solve, and cleverness is helpful in doing that.

So my question is: are the people who think certain abstraction techniques are too clever opposed to cleverness *per se*, or is there some other reason for the objection?

EDIT: [This parser combinator](http://shaurz.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/haskell-style-parser-combinators-in-scheme/) is an example of what I would consider to be clever code. I downloaded this and looked it over for about half an hour. Then I stepped through the macro expansion on paper and saw the light. Now that I understand it, it seems much more elegant than the Haskell parser combinator.

Comment: I think perhaps you're misunderstanding - cleverness in a *person* is a virtue, but cleverness in a *system* is a vice. Systems and code should not be clever, they should be clear as crystal. It often takes a clever individual to create such things.

Comment: Similar to [What's so bad about creative coding?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/23845/whats-so-bad-about-creative-coding)

Comment: @nlawalker: I think I get it now. People use the word "clever" when referring to code as an antonym for "clear" or "simple" because they really mean to use a word that *is* an antonym for "clear" or "simple".

Comment: @Axidos: That confirms what I was beginning to suspect (see my comment to nlawalker).

Comment: @Larry: Ha, I actually deleted my comment since I felt it too closely duplicated what Anna Lear said. But regarding the appropriateness of the term _clever_, think of it this way: there are a lot of appropriate antonyms for simple we could use (_convoluted_ comes to mind) but none of them describe the exact nature of the monstrosity like _clever_ does.

Comment: @Axidos: So do you really mean clever as in evil genius?

Comment: @Larry: I'm not sure what that would imply. Clever as in [inventive, original, ingenius](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clever) and by implication using things in a way you've never seen before. Sometimes it's great (a lot of design patterns are clever) but the foreignness of the solution could also make it difficult to work with.

Comment: @nlawalker: you should post that as an answer.

Comment: This Is relevant but may be offensive for some: [Why Ruby?](http://vimeo.com/17420638)

Comment: @Axidos: The link you posted is interesting because it lists "stupid" and "clumsy" as antonyms for "clever".

Comment: @Larry: Think you hit the nail on the head there.  Clever does not mean unclear.

Comment: @Larry: You are very caught up in antonyms here. Could you clarify where you're coming from? Are you contesting the appropriateness of the word _Clever_ to describe the situation, or are you trying to define it by seeking out what it _isn't_? Either way your attention to antonyms is causing some strife here.

Comment: @Axidos: we can let the antonym thing drop. Did you have a chance to check out the link I posted?

Comment: @Larry: I don't understand Scheme or Haskell yet - I can't comment.

Comment: @Axidos: I would really recommend learning those, excellent languages, really helped my general understanding of software engineering long ago when I learnt them.

Comment: @Axidos: I edited my question to indicate why I selected that particular code as an example.

Comment: Check out this Google Talks video on flexible design: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3q_y8H1ZTo&feature=sub

Comment: Does no-one comment code any more? That's where you explain the cleverness, so those that follow can understand. Like you in 6 months time.

Comment: @Phil: so long as the cleverness is necessary to accomplish some goal, then by all means leave it there with a why-type comment.  More often than not, though, cleverness in code is only there to show off.  In those cases, is it better to refactor with prejudice to something more clear.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Simple solutions are better for long-term maintenance. And it's not always just about language familiarity. A complex line (or lines) takes time to figure out even if you're an expert in the given language. You open up a file and start reading: "ok, simple, simple, got it, yep, WTF?!" Your brain comes to a screeching halt and you now have to stop and decipher a complicated line. Unless there was a measurable, concrete reason for that implementation, it is "too clever".

Figuring out what's going on gets progressively harder as complexity grows from a clever method to a clever class to a clever pattern. Aside from well-known approaches, you have to figure out the thought process that went into creating a "clever" solution, which can be quite difficult.

That said, I hate avoiding a pattern (when its use is justified) just because someone might not understand it. It's up to us as developers to keep learning and if we don't understand something, it's a reason to learn it, not to avoid it.

Comment: +1 Nicely said. I think it's a balance thing. If I can expect someone with a decent amount of knowledge to understand the code with a little thinking of himself, you can go for clever and maybe add a comment. If it takes four times as long to understand the code just because someone wanted to prove their coding skills - nah! If someone is smart enough to come up with a clever solution, they should be smart enough to decide whether it's understandable or not. Otherwise it's just showing off.

Comment: The last paragraph I like.  The rest is true, but unfortunate.

Comment: Looks like you've seen the source code to Zend PHP :)

Comment: +1 A simple pattern may not perform as well as a *clever* pattern, and like you said, it's up to us as developers to continue to push the envelope of "clever" by understanding it.

Comment: The only valid measurement of code quality: WTFs/m. http://www.osnews.com/images/comics/wtfm.jpg

Comment: @Stephen: If it's excessively “clever”, it's not really a pattern; it's just a standardized form of confusion. Mind you, that's not to say that intelligent patterns shouldn't be used intelligently, not at all! Instead, my feeling is that a smart piece of design is one that achieves its goals (right result, fast, etc.) while making it easy for someone else to understand.

Comment: Particularly for unusual patterns - a "this uses xxx pattern - see http://martinfowler.com/" comment may be helpful. It's not always Martin Fowlers fault, I suppose, but...

Comment: +1 for not just spewing quotes :)

Comment: This is very true.  This also implies that the language should be designed so the powerful constructions are easy to read.  A typical example is the original for-loop in C based languages, compared with "for(String s: strings)" in later versions of Java.

Comment: This answer conflates *complexity* with *cleverness*. Those are not the same thing. I would agree that simple is often better than complicated, but not that clever equals complicated.  Clever is about intelligence being required to have created it.  It doesn't mean it's hard to understand, once it's been created.  For example, an iPhone required lots of intelligent solutions to create, but the product is something that's simple to understand.  Another example might be the programming interview.  The questions often involve figuring out a clever trick, to simplify, or speed up the code.

Comment: @Nate Not conflating so much as making a deliberate argument that the bad kind of "clever" typically leads to unnecessary complexity and/or confusion. (Since the question was framed from the "why is it harmful" standpoint.)

Comment: The question was posed as to whether people are really opposed to cleverness, per se, not *when* clever **can** be bad.  Your answer was all about why complexity is bad, and really said nothing about cleverness.  Unless you specify that it's complexity that's really the problem, and *sometimes*, clever solutions can lead to complexity, you are binding the two concepts.  You don't acknowledge that there is a good kind of clever in your actual answer, which is why this is the textbook definition of "conflation".  By the way, I've yet to find anyone who ever thought they were conflating concepts.

Comment: As someone who has had to justify doing something "clever" when it was really just "minimally, orthogonally correct", I would like to add that there is some subjectivity on the question of what exactly is clever. For example, some people will always want to write out `if FuncX() then return true, else return false`, and will never want you to just write `return FuncX()`.  I'm not kidding, I've literally had that conversation.  Because people want somewhere to hang their breakpoints, or something. :-)

Comment: @WarrenP Yeah, there's a good amount of subjectivity here. I've had the "we can't use language feature X because then other developers will have to learn about language feature X" conversation and it's not fun. The horrifyingly bad "clever" solutions are more in the "you know it when you see it" area. DailyWTF has a good library of those by now. :)

Comment: Even something that appears simpler can be too "clever". The original question mentions abstraction. In Java land there have been actually studies that show high levels of inheritance make code less maintainable. People just have to keep too much invisible functionality from the class hierarchy in their head to work on or understand the code. Maybe you have simpler files by breaking them into a 10 class inheritance hierarchy, but it still hurts the software engineering side of things. The question's link is the same. Inventing new stuff that can only be understood by reading a paper.

Answer (score 102):

## KISS Principle

Keep it simple, stupid. Clever solutions are great, but often the simplest straight forward solution is best.

> “Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.”

Brian Kernighan

Comment: I would say it's pretty close to always that more simple is better.

Comment: @Walter: There are time where a concise complex solution is better then a longer more straight forward one. But those cases are rare.

Comment: On the other hand, if you write code as cleverly as you can, you then must learn to debug it, and in doing so you become more clever.  Or something like that.

Comment: @James: Or you just fail. ;)

Comment: @Josh K: I've *always* known KISS as "Keep It Simple, Stupid!" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: @Orbling: I recalled it differently, oh well, now I know.

Comment: @Josh K: In fairness, I thought you may have just cleaned it up a bit, less offensive version or something. :-)

Comment: ***"Keep it simple and be stupid"***, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)? :) Does this mean *keeping it simple is stupid* or that *to keep it simple you must be stupid*? :P

Comment: I honestly do not like how clever is construed, but it's true that this is the general understanding of clever in this context.  Personally if I were to use the regular definition of clever to describe an implementation of something, it would be simple, because in programming doing something in a clever way would be doing something in a simple way.  Thanks for ruining this word, Brian Kernighan, __ass hole__.

Comment: The important of this quote is that 'clever' is used as a polite euphemism of code that is too complex to be easily understood.  It isn't saying that one should not be intelligent but rather that taking giant leaps of non-obvious reasoning is to be avoided.  Maintaining code should not be like solving riddles.

Answer (score 83):

Fools ignore complexity; pragmatists suffer it; experts avoid it; geniuses remove it.
-- Alan Perlis

Comment: +1 for the nice quote and for being the first answer without the implicit assumption that something can't be both simple and clever

Comment: What is important is that it is the programmer who is supposed to be clever, not the code.

Comment: Way better quote then an idiot misusing the word clever in a clever way.

Answer (score 30):

The best solution is not always the most clever solution. Sometimes simple solutions are equally good.

In Software you always need to think in terms of maintainability. If a piece of code is too clever for someone who is going to maintain it, I would say that cleverness is not worth it.

Comment: A simple solution to a complex problem is about as clever as anyone can get.

Comment: although there is always the caveat that you don't want to over-simplify just because the maintainer can't code (or read it).

Comment: @confusedGeek - but if you know the maintenance programmer's can't handle it, then the clever solution becomes a time bomb. Balance is key here - and this only applies if you happen to know the maintenance team. If you have no idea, then being clear in your cleverness is the best you can do.

Comment: @Michael, performance constraints may require that your code be clever.  It is then the maintainer's job to learn, and if they can't, hire new maintainers.

Comment: @Stephen, if the code NEEDS to be clever, the programmer should take great care to explain WHY it needs to be, so the maintainer do not have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 26):

To quote Brian Kernighan:

*“Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.”*

Comment: "... Unless you used the correct definition of clever and the code is actually simple to understand and debug."

Comment: Depends on whcich dictionary you thumb, I guess. In my experience, any "clever" code - easy to udnerstand or not - still exploits a fortunate conjunction in the spec. Even if it's obvious, it should be marked if such an assumption may change and shouldn't leak to different parts of the code.

Comment: You are right, but I'd like to add the caveat that it depends on how easy the language and implementation is to read and understand, and your comments may just be code noise instead of something helpful.  And while it is common to use clever to mean its opposite, we should strive to be more clear so others cannot misconstrue things for their own advantage.

Comment: No objection to that :)

Answer (score 22):

cleverness is a tool; by itself it is not harmful. It only becomes harmful in context where it is not necessary.

Answer (score 16):

"Clever", when applied to code, is almost always just a euphemism for "needlessly complicated".

Reading good, clear, simple code is hard enough. Reading "clever" code is like studying latin poetry all over again.

The confusion arises because "clever" as an attribute of a person has a completely different meaning. This case can also be seen as an example of why designing software for real people is hard: Because they are ambiguous.

And because some programmers suffer to understand the social protocols most people follow, which forbid them to directly denounce code as "needlessly complicated", they may find it hard to differentiate between the two meanings of the word *clever*. Contrary to what some may think, I think ultimately better "people persons" (meaning: people who have empathy and introspection and patience) make better developers. Because they know who to write for.

Comment: I would have upvoted this had you not gotten preachy about social protocols and "people persons [sic]".

Comment: That's OK- and thanks for reminding me. I tend to get too preachy. But I'm rellay irked by some (many?) Programmers' inability and/or unwillingness to deal with ordinary human behavior, and the general lack of empathy and introspection I see in our field. Maybe I should've put "people persons" in quotes instead of italics. English is not my first language, I just didn't know how to get the point across shorter that, in order to be a great developer, you have to understand not only code, but people too. IMHO.

Comment: Edited my answer. Clearer/less offensive now?

Comment: +1 for the first sentence, which I had actually concluded after getting the first few answers.

Comment: Yes, thank you for clarifying how clever is being used by stupid people in this context!

Comment: @JasonBaker Yeah, GOD forbid someone explain things in a humanitarian context, we don't want people to actually __care__ about their lives and those around them. Sorry about using "GOD" here but I found the other things I wanted to say even more inappropriate.

Comment: And you call yourself a Python programmer, a group that typically preaches about providing humanitarian benefits and approaching the problem of software in a humanitarian way. GTFO man.

Comment: @fzwo Instead of saying "people persons" you can say "usability experts" as it's much more clearly related to people aspect of software.

Answer (score 9):

Most folks are focusing on cleverness from an aspect of "The code requires too much deciphering to figure out what it is doing" and all the bad things that go along with that such as

1. No one else can figure it out, let alone maintain it/debug it.
2. The person who wrote doesn't even know what it does.
3. It may actually be not all that brilliant to begin with
4. etc....

All good points, but there's another negative aspect of cleverness and that is the old ego problem. This causes issues along the lines of

1. Someone that is too "Smart" to use anyone else's solutions. Why look for what other people have done when you can invent your own way of skinning the same cat?
2. Someone who thinks they've invented the coolest solution to a problem will often refuse to take any input.
3. Won't let anyone modify "their" code even when there's obvious issues or a trivial change is needed.
4. Somewhat conversely, they think they're smart and need to use the "latest" technique to prove how smart they are but fail to get a good handle on it in either personal projects or otherwise non-production code before rolling it into critical parts of the system.

We're all guilty of too much ego sometimes, but when it gets in the way of the team it's a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Good Clever -- high ratio between clever lines of code vs lines of in a non-clever alternative. 20 lines of code that saves you from writing 20000 is Extremely Good Clever. Good Clever is about saving yourself work.

Bad Clever -- low ratio between lines of code written written vs. lines of code saved. One line of clever code that saves you from writing five lines of code is Bad Clever. Bad clever is about "syntactic masturbation".

Just to note: Bad Clever is almost never called "Bad Clever"; it will often travel under the aliases "beautiful", "elegant", "concise", or "succinct."

Comment: Interesting answer, but is code that you call "Bad Clever" actually referred to as "beautiful", etc., by anyone other than the person who wrote the code in question?

Comment: Depends. In Objective-C/C++/C, the phenomenon is usually limited to an individual. In Perl and Ruby, often the entire community will have a shared value about Bad Clever being "beautiful", "elegant", etc.

Comment: @user8865: also, "Good Clever" code ends up being much easier to debug than the original since there's by your definition 3 orders of magnitude less of it.

Comment: Ah, so Perl programs are - now almost by definition - Extremely Good Clever :)  Nice to know!

Answer (score 7):

I have to wonder about everyone's definition of clever.

Personally, I feel like I have been clever when I have taken a hard, complex problem, and implemented it in a very simple and straight forward way, while maintaining an acceptable level of efficiency.

tl;dr i feel clever when, during a code review, my reviewer says "wow, that was easier than i thought it was going to be", as opposed to "wtf is all this.."

Comment: LOL about the tl;dr, how slow do you think programmers read?  Yes, I absolutely despise the misuse of clever here to mean the opposite of what it actually is.  Dumb/Ignorant/Evil developers and managers actually use this to justify not hiring someone who they think may be "too smart".

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the theory answers listed, often this gets used in the context of too clever for everyone else.

Move between a top tier performance intensive team and a medium tier maintenance team sometime to see the real life differences in what is "too clever".

Leaving out the theory arguments, too clever is often based on what the least skilled team members can work with reasonably, so it is very relative to the environment.

Comment: Excellent: *"too clever is often based on what the least skilled team members can work with reasonably"*

Comment: depending on your location this is somewhat less than "excellent" at times :-)

Comment: Who cares about the least skilled member of the team?  Almost every team (though I'm sure there are a few exceptions) has at least one member who has absolutely no business calling him/herself a programmer.

Comment: Hopefully you are getting them to be better, but even when that is not successful you still have to deal with them as a team member and they need to be able to participate in some of the work.  I am currently seeing this in lambda expressions.  A lot of people I work with don't get them yet so they see them as too clever.  This is unfortunate as they solve a lot of our problems quite efficiently and elegantly, but if none of the middle tier guys get them they will go to management for the software being unsupportable.

Comment: @Bill:  Lambda functions???  Anyone who can't understand something that simple, even after explicitly being asked to go learn about them, has no business being a professional programmer.

Comment: Lambdas are something I see otherwise competent people just have trouble really grasping sometimes.  There are examples in DLR and even things like ycombinator in linq that are too clever for me to modify.  Like most things it depends greatly on the audience.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes I've been so clever that I've been wrong.

Comment: That can happen.  And sometimes, something's so wrong, its right.

Comment: They call those theories John.  Theories can and should be wrong once and a while :), it doesn't mean we should stop being clever and striving to be as clever as possible.  How else will we become leaders in this world!  "Ah, but a man's reach should exceed his grasp -- or what's a heaven for?"

Answer (score 4):

Performant, maintainable, timely and cheap are the ways I measure a solution.  I guess clever could also be part of a solution as long as it doesn't negatively affect those qualities.

Comment: +1 for using "cheap" as a positive in regards to development

Comment: I've seen too much 'clever' code that is not performant!

Comment: There are more valuable metrics, but those can be good ones depending on the project, and often they are at odds with each other so you have to emphasize one over the other in order to succeed.

Answer (score 3):

If clever code + the amount of comments required to make it understandable code <= simple code, then I say go for the clever code.  Every time.

I think the problem arises when people who write "clever code" deliberately fail to comment it properly, because only by it being initially incomprehensible will future generations who come across it have to spend time "appreciating" how clever it is.

Comment: Well, or because they just don't think about the next guy, or whatever. I'm not sure I'd attribute to intellectual egotism what can adequately be explained by unthinking sloth and bad habit. But the fact is, if your code can't be comprehended at first glance, it needs comments, and if the code + comments is longer (in LOC or time) than another way, you're working harder than you need to.

Comment: Good answer, (can't +1, none left, will later).  If people spend no time writing clever code and others spend no time understanding it, preferring less complex simple code, even if less efficient.  Then no advancement in skill will take place.

Comment: Best answer. The mantra: write simple baseline, starter code that's braindead and slow as all get up...and then make it a comment when you boil it down to an unreadable one-liner. That's how you learn all the dirty tricks in your language!

Comment: If I take your use of clever to mean convoluted, I have personally written some convoluted code that was made comprehensible through logging. While I didn't plan on writing convoluted code, at the time, it saved me some time, but I added a # TODO that it probably should be rewritten to be simple if we need to modify it significantly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reminded of a quote I've seen attributed to many different people, as the good quotes often are.

To paraphrase:

> Any intelligent person can make the
>   simple complex, it takes a genius to
>   make the complex simple.

Taking a complex idea and simplifying it so it's understandable shows the cleverness of the constructor but taking a simple idea and making it complex shows the constructor wants to be seen as clever.

Comment: Yes, it's the egocentric idea of wanting to be clever that makes your code base convoluted.  You either are, or are not clever. Sadly, in initial learning stages people think they are more clever then they are. Later on they realize how not clever they are and actually then write clever code once they fill out the gaps in knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

If the 'clever' solution is difficult to figure out, then it shouldn't be used. For instance, if through side effects you can contract a complex calculation to one line, it's clever. But if it takes an hour for someone else to figure out what in the world you did, it's too clever.

Comment: Fair enough, but does your answer change if the person who can't figure out the code isn't familiar with all of the features of the language?

Comment: That's different, at least IMO. If a person isn't familiar with the features of a language, then they aren't in a position to judge what's clever or not.

Comment: @Larry: Not necessarily. I would assume that the person reading it is at a basic/low advanced level of proficiency. And if it starts getting irretrievable complex, then it's time to put in a block comment explaining what the code is supposed to do, which will help establish a frame of reference for understanding what it's actually doing. The comment should be high-level, though - write out the calculation, explain the process; don't repeat the code. A person at should (ideally) be able to understand the code as he reads it. That's the goal, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, cleverness per se isn't a problem. Usually we can make confusions about "clever" (without sarcasm) and "insightfull" code. What I see as a problem, is the fact that usually the "clever" (with sarcasm) code contains implicit not-visible requirements, making it harder to debug and maintain along time.

There are several known algorithms that are clever. [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is one, IMO.

"Clever" (with sarcasm) code usually make assumptions about variables being set and states of the system that are virtually disconnected from the "clever" code (as files opened previously, network connections, databases, etc...).

The amount of data you have to load on your brain to maintain correctly a "clever" code is usually to big to have a good cost-benefit ratio.

Answer (score 1):

"Clever code" is any code for which the programmer had to think really hard or use some advanced skill to write it. The problem with that it disregards the need for a certain "cleverness margin", best expressed by Brian W. Kernighan:

"Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."

Answer (score 1):

Because what looks like *cleverness* to a developer in a burst of creativity can simply pass as *mess* and just be an *unreadable*, *unmaintainable* block of *obscure riddles* for others.

Still, a nice, clever, well-performing block of riddles, but if you have the experience, you'll often realize that it will cost your business (not you, the developer) at lot more to maintain that thing on the medium- or long-term. So you prefer to calm the ardor of your fellow developers when they get carried.

Except, of course, if there's a justification for the cleverness. And if there's a good documentation that comes along with the obfuscated thing you just wrote. You did comment that clever piece of code, right? Explain it's intent, why it needs to be like, and how it behaves?

If there's no justification, then it's probably just either premature optimization, over-engineering, or a YAGNI kind of problem. If it takes 15 levels of indirection to do something simple, then there's a good chance you fall under of the previous categories as well. And if it's not documented, then it's just trouble.

Great code shouldn't require the maintainer to be at 100% all the time to understand it. 
Good code is clever. Great code can be almost as efficient, but better in many other aspects. Great code shouldn't require an IDE with 15 views to follow your application's design.

*Note: hey, I've written a few stuff I thought to be clever but that drew WTF? out of - if not my co-developers' - my manager's mouth. Have to look at it from their perspective.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You seem to be agreeing with the others who say that "clever" doesn't mean what I thought it did.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to be **clever**, but I strive to be **elegant**.

Develop code **now** that others will not try and avoid **later**.

Comment: Come on... clever is a synonym for elegant, your brain has been marketeered. Yes, I made that word up, it means you brain is influenced by marketing instead of truth.

Comment: Elegant: simple *and* clever. @DerekLitz +1 for cromulent anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding of the issue, based on my experience and the other answers:

1. Code that took cleverness to write, but comes out readable and maintainable is not considered harmful. However, most developers would not call that kind of code "clever"; they may use a different term like "elegant". There may or may not be some debate about whether such code exists.
2. Production code that requires significant time and effort to understand even by a seasoned developer familiar with the language is "clever" and considered harmful by everyone.
3. Production code that requires significant time and effort by inexperienced developers is considered harmful by some. I've seen answers either way, and I've worked with developers who've said explicitly that they would prefer to keep everything "lowest common denominator".

Comment: The entirety of modern western culture is LCD, I guess that means programming has to be too; not good.

Comment: @Orbling: Yes, but don't forget instant gratification.

Comment: I like your points of experience.  It's sad that people are not striving for iterative improvement and investing into each other by sharing knowledge and understanding.  Instead they'd rather have us be cogs on a wheel so we can be easily replaced when the time comes.  By doing this we are impeding progress.  We are also selling ourselves short...

Answer (score 1):

I know a guy; he is probably the most brilliant person I have ever met. He is definitely an unbelievable coder, probably better than I will ever be in my entire life in terms of sheer programming chops. He writes code like he's typing a word document and can reverse a linked list like you wouldn't believe. If you want to talk about writing some seriously complex code, he's your man and if I run into an unbelievably hard problem I always turn to him. However, working on a project with him in a team setting is excruciating. He is unable to directly target the business problem and provide a logical, efficient, and concise solution to it. For him, a code listing of 1000 lines would be better than 100. Instead of using the tools provided to him via the IDE or framework, he will roll his own super-optimized tool. This is all well and good except for when other team members are waiting on him to finish something, or we have a deadline.

While I admire his ability to do these complex things, what I need is someone that can solve the problem and move on. Its not great to say, or admit, but sometimes in a business setting time is everything and you have to just solve the problem and get on with your life, you can always come back to it later and refactor the hell out of it to improve your code. There is a fine line between being clever and also being a pain in the butt. My motto for my team is always, what is the simplest possible thing that will work in this situation and then go from there. Sometimes simpler isn't always the answer but its a damn good place to start.

Comment: Sorry, despite the quality of this person you met to be able to code complex things, he is stupid.  People can be and are stupid regardless of their other traits.  Your statements of what you really want out of development are obvious to a talented person.  If he is truly intelligent you should do him a favor and confront him instead of let him do stupid things with his talent.  You are doing a disservice to him and everyone around him by being idle and complaining behind his back.  If he is not intelligent you should fire him, then maybe he'll get it.

Comment: I do have a relation to a primary resource who has dealt with intelligent people daily for decades and some of them are just missing a few pieces of knowledge to be productive in a team environment.  They can figure it out on their own if you at least let them know about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"Clever" in this context means "too clever for its own good", i.e. something that works now but will be a nightmare to understand and change later on.

Especially if it's a trick that exploits an obscure feature of the programming language, or makes use of weird side-effects, or is a really bizarre way of solving the problem in the target language.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Simple solutions, I really like the ruby way. When you want to for example sum first 2 elements on the list. first you cut the list to make it have size=2 and then you sum it.

I remember that once I used 1 list instead of 3 and create one big function that was very hard to maintain/change.

**in todays world we don't have to sacrifice code clearness for performance**(except c++, they don't have to, but they will).

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you need to be 'clever' its to workaround a problem in code. Ifs a workaround and not very straightforward then you'll get a lot of confused faces or othertimes weird side effects when assuming certain conditions (which may be 100% correct at the time of writing the code)

Thus clever == confusing == bad :(
But its also awesome as i used them for practical solutions to limited problems.

Answer (score 0):

Re-quoting for context and and easier comprehension:

> "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug it."

What Brian Kernighan wrote here obviously refers to convolution, and he mistakenly used the word clever.

> "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as [convoluted] as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug it."

Convolution:

```
A thing that is complex and difficult to follow.
```

Clever:

```
Showing intelligence or skill; ingenious
```

Educated programmers know that simple code is ingenious. Code that is as clever as possible should be simple by definition. Educated programmers will also avoid working with and writing convoluted code like the plague.  They will also turn convoluted code into clever code whenever they have the chance.  Code usually starts out convoluted and approaches cleverness as knowledge about the domain and understanding of human cognitive ability in programming is better understood through experience and shared knowledge.

Because of the popularity of this quote and Brian Kernighan being quite popular in the industry this misuse of the word has a negative social impact and I'd honestly like to see that addressed by the man himself.  Before writing this article I tried to see if I could simply e-mail him, but, I was unable to find any email contact information that I understood :(.

The negative social impact I have seen is other programmers ostracizing their more clever peers, because they now see cleverness as a problem.  The real problem is the stupid peers who think they are being clever by doing things in a new unidiomatic way, and constantly inventing new things when there is no advantage instead of gaining and understanding of the greater community and reusing clever ideas as much as possible.

I do need to clarify though that **often** gaining an understanding is more difficult than inventing your own.  Because of the common problem in industry for unrealistic deadlines inventing your own for your smaller niche problem will be used to save time. This is based on the observation that useful, reusable things usually target a larger niche, or provide a useful abstraction for invention.  It is also based on the **fact** that people target large niches to make more money, when often this makes the tool extremely hard to use because of the complexity involved in making something usable for a wide area of applications.

The other negative social impact is this prevents progress and the desire to comprehend because in our egocentric world we will immediately be in denial of our own lack of understanding and write off the code of as being convoluted even if, once understood, the idea is actually quite clever.

TODO I'd like to cite some references but I'd also like the lack of references to not impede my ability to share information so I will quickly cite what I remember as the sources of my information and maybe I will find the actual info some day (or you can find it for me! :)

- Guido Van Rossum's talk about event loops and how he came to understand them
- A GitHub employee who stated that they avoid hiring clever people on Y-Combinator
- Much of the discussion and learning that goes on in the Python community.  The Python community is especially critical of new ideas, but does not dismiss new ideas they do not understand out of hand, and you can typically see features that were at first seen as convoluted see the light of day as a core language feature/package.
- My own experience and professional opinion based on my 10000 foot observations.  I can't really see the specifics to enlighten from all the way up there though :( Hopefully your experience and observation will tell you the same thing and someone else can comment below to give this answer some merit.

Feel free to add your own citations!  Also, feel free to add commas to my text. I have not refreshed my knowledge of comma usage in English in quite some time...

Answer (score -1):

Because often people don't know a language, idioms and patterns. They could take a book and learn it, but they don't. And because of those people you should write simple code.

It's not a cleverness. It's a knowledge.

Comment: I certainly don't agree with this (although not worth a -1).  By this argument you could say that you wouldn't implement the Command pattern to handle a Undo/Redo transaction stack because the maintainers were fresh out of school and didn't understand what was going on.  At some point you have to just say that if they don't know it they need to learn it.

Comment: @confusedGeek Quite right, where do you draw the line on ignorance?

Comment: @Orbling, honestly that's the hard part and to some degree depends on the situation.  The general guide I tend to use that is if a reasonably seasoned developer (knowledgeable in the technologies used) can grok it then it's probably ok.  If they can't then it needs to be refactored (or review hiring practices).

Comment: @confusedGeek Aye, sounds sensible.  The litmus test is probably, can a developer of the same calibre as yourself understand easily what you have done quickly enough.  If not and there is an easier way, then it needs changing.  Sometimes there is not an easier way.

Comment: -1.  Don't code for the lowest common denominator.  **Unnecessary** complexity is bad, but if some cleverness makes the code substantially more DRY, etc. it may be worth it.

Comment: @dsimcha, not "lowest" but "average". Complexity is relative thing, so your "cleverness" can make code not-understandable for most of your co-workers. For example, in C\C++ (sic!) you can use classes and CRTP to remove duplication, but if your co-workers like write in C-style and don't get classes and templates, your cleverness won't bring anything good to project. Replace CRTP with boost.MPL if you think that CRTP is too easy.

Comment: @Abyx I agree with you.  But you do need to take your immediate surroundings into context.  Do you work with 100 other developers as clever as you?  Well go balls to the wall!!  Do you work with 1 other developer who is stupid?  Well before you get a new job you'll probably have to make some money writing code, so I'd consider it unethical to leave the company strapped with a stupid developer and code he can't understand because you used the latest and greatest techniques.  Help that developer understand what he needs to and dumb it down a bit, then move on.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find the word discipline mentioned anywhere around here, so I'll chip in. I do not want to post **the** answer, but to share a different insight on the matter, maybe one that the original question did not have in mind.

A clever developer is a good thing.

However, before cleverness come other traits. As you might have realized I will talk about **discipline**. A clever and undisciplined developer can be very bad for the long term maintainability of the system.

Suppose that a bug arises or a new requirement comes in. A clever developer might soon realize that a couple local fixes will get the job done in 2 minutes. If that developer is disciplined he will restrain from applying those fixes to the source code and will, instead, find a meaningful way to compose the desired behavior to the system. This way, the next time the need will arise to modify the particular pieces of code the maintainer will have an easy time to understand the code and implement the new changes without breaking anything. If not, well you get the picture.

Comment: "Beatings Will Continue until Morale Improves"

Comment: @gnat Meaning? To clear things up a bit; I do not take discipline as something being forced upon developers. It is a good personality trait. One that is usually developed by smart people after some time of maintaining software. The problem comes with clever people that have not been in the maintainer position enough and leave clever bombs everywhere for others to find.